# How to fire an event on changing the text of a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn?

Tags: c#

I got a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn. how can i fire a textchanged event on the same.

```
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvColumnTextBox = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        dgvColumnTextBox.Name = "Alias";
        dataGridView.Columns.Add(dgvColumnTextBox);
```

I need to fire the event on changing the text of any of the cells in the column "Alias". Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the CellValueChanged event . http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx , or look for a CellChanged event in the control.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGridViewCell cell_Changed = null;
DataGridViewCell cell_Begin = null;
string cell_Begin_Save = "";
bool cell_Reset = false;

private void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int colIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
    int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;

    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        cell_Changed = DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    }

    if (cell_Changed != null)
    {
        if (cell_Begin_Save != cell_Changed.Value.ToString())
        {
            DataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
            cell_Reset = false;
        }
    }
}

private void DataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int colIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
    int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;

    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && !cell_Reset)
    {
        cell_Begin = DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        cell_Begin_Save = cell_Begin.Value.ToString();
        cell_Reset = true;
    }
}

private void DataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    cell_Reset = false;
}
```